# Python script runs manually on google vm, but gets killed if put in while true loop for scheduling

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, cpu-usage

I have a python script that runs fine when I run it via `python3 script.py &` on the the google vm, but then when i detach it with a `screen` and leave it run a couple iterations on its own I come back to check and it gets killed.

I think it might be something to do with high cpu usage, i tried to do a while true loop and sleep the program for a while, then i tried to use `apscheduler` or just `scheduler` or even `nice -n 19 python3 script.py` but neither worked out, the thing is that the script seems to run fine the first time or even first two times, but then it gets killed.

Here is how I run my script, is there anyway i can solve this without upping my CPU? I think I have a small machine on vm.

```
schedule.every(10).minute.do(scheduled_job)
print('STARTED PROGRAM')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/usr/bin/time --verbose python3 script.py` to measure memory used by a single job run, or use `ps axu` or `top` to do that for a continuously looping task. Verify that you malloc less than the VM container agrees to provide.

If you see your process killed while testing on a small linux host, look for clues in the log: `$ zgrep oom /var/log/{syslog,messages}*`